# flash / as2 - combobox "z-index" issue with other components in the swf

Tags: flash, position, actionscript-2, layer

I have a simple AS2 search form done in flash, the issue I'm seeing is the combobox drop down menu is appearing underneath other comboboxes on the stage, see the screenshot below.

Is there a bit of AS2 code or something that I can use so when the component is clicked it positions it above all other components on the stage so this doesn't happen? I'm a newbie to as2 so I'm wondering if there is a z-index/position:absolute style property for the component that I could use.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look into the `DepthManager` class:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002311.html

Answer (score 1):

A quick way is to use the getNextHighestDepth and swapDepths function on the currently focussed component, like this:

```
this.swapDepths(this.getNextHighestDepth());
```